# print CSS still showing some background images when printing

Tags: css, printing, css-sprites

I am receiving some strange begaviour in IE6 when printing a page.

For some reason it is printing out parts of a CSS background image sprite.

I have overridden all background-image declarations with:

```
* {background-image:none !important;}
```

But to no avail. I didn't think background images were supported by default anyways so this is a new one on me.

Comment: IE does not support the !important in some circumstances: It will always take the last value set for the same property within the same set of rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work in IE6 because it doesn't support the * identifier. You will have to override the background for every element seperately.

Comment: As stated before i have a seperate stylesheet for print using the media="print".

This is the issue that in IE6 some images are still shouwing up.

Comment: What do you mean 'as stated before'; it's not in your question.
In that case it doesn't work because IE6 does not support the * identifier. I will edit my answer.